# What is the meaning of the way that Kirk's clothes are?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-uniforms

I just want to know more about Kirk's clothes. Does he wear them all the time? Does he ever wear colors other than yellow? Yellow looks good on him.

Comment: His clothes are from a standardized military uniform. Although (if modern militaries can be used for extrapolation) service-members have a small degree of discretion as to which uniforms they wear while on vacation, there is generally a specific uniform designated for each type of occasion.

Answer (score 32):

James Tiberius Kirk has had a wide variety of uniforms over the years.

**Classic Uniform Kirk** as seen in many TOS episodes:

[image]

**Green Tunic Kirk** as seen in "Trouble With Tribbles"

[image]

**Dress Uniform Kirk** from "Journey to Babel"

[image: Dress Uniform]

**Turtle-neck Kirk** from "Where No Man Has Gone Before" (h/t to O.R. Mapper for reminding me)

[image]

**Evil Kirk** worn in "Mirror, Mirror"

[image]

**Open Blazer Kirk** from *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*

[image]

**Cold Weather Kirk** from *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*

[image]

**White Tunic Kirk** from *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*

[image]

**Shapless Ugly Brown Jacket Kirk** from *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*

[image]

**Admiral "Two-tone" Kirk** from *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*

[image]

**Odd Wifebeater Kirk** from *Star Trek: Generations*

[image]

**Large black V-neck Kirk** from *Star Trek: The Animated Series* (possibly a redux of his uniform from TOS)

[image]

And of course, ladies' favourite - **Shirtless Kirk**...

[image]

You can find more information [here](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2009/03/19/the-many-looks-of-captain-kirk?page=12).

Comment: LOL @ Wifebeater Kirk

Comment: Do we know what color his girdle is?

Comment: According to Shatner he never wore a girdle; http://www.aoltv.com/2006/05/25/shatner-never-wore-a-girdle-says-shatner/ he claims that he broke a rib during a horse-riding accident and sent for a compression bandage. A few days later a rumour appeared in the press stating that he wore a corset.

Comment: +1 For "Odd Wifebeater Kirk". If I could I'd give another +1 for Shirtless Kirk too - although I'm not sure shirtless is a colour of shirt.

Comment: NICE JOB!  Though you did miss Space-Suit Kirk as seen in "Web of the Tholians" but that's understandable as it's not as sexy a look as Shirtless Kirk =]

Comment: Is the space suit a uniform in the strictest sense?

Comment: I think this answer needs to be tidied up - sorting, and some explanations would be helpful. The uniforms listed here span three uniform design eras (and those are not exactly grouped in the answer), so it's not like they were all part of the same uniform set and could possibly appear in parallel. "Large black V-neck Kirk from Star Trek: The Animated Series" and "Classic Uniform Kirk as seen in many TOS episodes:" are the *same* uniform - that one is drawn and the other one filmed as live-action doesn't make them different uniform variants. 'Evil Kirk worn in "Mirror, Mirror"' doesn't ...

Comment: ... quite belong into this list, as that was essentially Kirk dressing up (technically speaking, not exactly, but you get the idea) for a context that is *not* the Federation Starfleet from our universe. If the mirror universe uniform counts, you could just as well list the Nazi uniforms from *Patterns of Force*, or other uniform-like clothes he may have worn, but I suppose that is beyond the intended scope of the question and the answer. The "Odd Wifebeater Kirk from Star Trek: Generations" may be a borderline case, as it's not clear whether such a west is not generally worn under the ...

Comment: ... red Star Trek II onwards uniforms by all characters. Lastly, the answer lacks a mention of the [turtleneck uniforms that were still in use in *Where No Man Has Gone Before*](http://www.stardestroyer.net/Empire/Tech/Ground/Kirk.jpg) and the [*Star Trek: The Motion Picture* field jackets](https://thepropstop.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/shatnertmp.jpg). Possibly, spacesuits might count too, as they are Starfleet-issued clothing, as well - both [those from TOS](http://mimg.ugo.com/200903/9027/thetholianweb064.jpg) and ...

Comment: ... [those from *The Motion Picture*](http://www.marcellorossi.info/Memory/Card02.jpg).

Comment: Mirror Universe Spock gets a cool goatee, Sulu gets a facial scar, and Kirk gets...bare shoulders?

Comment: @Monty129 - I'd love a uniform that shows off the big guns.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - These are excellent remarks. Feel free to edit them into the answer. That's the point of SE!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I disagree on the space-suits though. They might be standard issue, but they're not part of the standard uniform.

Comment: "Two tone Kirk" and "Admiral Kirk" are the same costume, aren't they?

Comment: @BenMiller - One is brown, the other is grey.

Comment: I agree with @BenMiller in that they're the same costume, and the apparent difference in colour is just due to lighting. The timing of the [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6peJ2yXizWY) corroborates that: "Admiral Kirk" is Kirk standing in the inspection pod gazing at the refit Enterprise. After Scott and Kirk end their space-side tour, the pod docks with the Enterprise, and Scott and Kirk leave the pod to step into a corridor where they meet Decker. This is what is shown in the "Two-Tone Kirk" image. There is simply no time (nor reason) for Kirk to switch uniforms in between.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper (and BenMiller) - I bow to your expertise :-)

Answer (score 8):

In the TOS-era, the Captain's tunic was actually green, with yellow marks near the wrists - this is a wraparound tunic:

[image: Kirk in captain's green wraparound tunic]

In that time period, [gold was for command, blue for sciences and medical, red for security and operations, and grey for cadets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(mid_2260s-early_2270s)#Division_colors).

Here's Kirk in a standard style green tunic:

[image: Kirk in standard green uniform]

Comment: That second photo is from the second pilot, "Where No Man Has Gone Before". That particular shirt was not seen in the rest of the series; the collar and braid were redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

I read, in one of the first Star Trek fan books back in the early 70s, that ALL of Kirk's tunics were Command Gold, but that a film processing error turned his Gold tunic Green in several episodes.

Comment: You should provide some evidence of this.

Comment: The green uniform was his "standard" uniform. As you can see from the pic above where some staff are wearing yellow uniforms alongside him; http://i.stack.imgur.com/PutuZ.jpg

Comment: this sounds like the "why is Data that colour" answer to me

Comment: I will have to check for references later, but wasn't it just the other way round? All uniforms being actually greenish, but appearing golden under studio lighting conditions, except for Kirk's non-standard tunic, which was made of a different material and thus retained its actual greenish hue when seen on tv?